# jQuery Mobile click events on dynamic list items

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm having trouble getting click events from list items.  In this page:

http://bec-systems.com/list-click.html

The first the entries in the list fire click events.  However, if I dynamically add 3 more events by pushing the "Refresh Update List" button, the next 3 list entries do not generate click events.

Appreciate any suggestions as to how I can make this work, or generally improve the code.

Thanks,
Cliff

Code is also listed below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Status</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#refreshUpdateButton").on("click", function(event, ui) {
    console.log("refreshUpdateButton")

    versions = ["0.3", "0.4", "0.5"]

    for (var i=0; i < versions.length; i += 1) {
      $("#updateVersionsList").append('<li><a id="updateVersionItem-' + (i+3) + '">' + versions[i] + '</a></li>');
      if ($("#updateVersionsList").hasClass('ui-listview')) {
        $("#updateVersionsList").listview("refresh");
      } else {
        $("#updateVersionsList").trigger('create');
      }
    }

  })

  $('[id^=updateVersionItem]').on("click", function(event, ui) {
    console.log("updateVersion, selected = " + $(this).attr('id'));
  })

});

  </script>
</head> 
<body> 

<!-- Software update page -->
<div data-role="page" id="software-update-page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Software Update</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
    <h1>Select Software version:</h1>
    <ul data-role="listview" id="updateVersionsList">
      <li><a id="updateVersionItem-0">0.0</a></li>
      <li><a id="updateVersionItem-1">0.1</a></li>
      <li><a id="updateVersionItem-2">0.2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <a data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" id="refreshUpdateButton">Refresh Update list</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what should happen on click? i dont see anything happen on the first three too

Comment: @zod, open up the developer tools on the browser and switch to Console tab.  clicks on the first three display information there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this form of `.on()` (per comments below).

```
  $(document).on("click", '[id^=updateVersionItem]', function(event, ui) {
    console.log("updateVersion, selected = " + $(this).attr('id'));
  })
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/YaAEJ/

Otherwise, whenever you dynamically add the new elements, you need to attach the click event to those items.

Assuming the following code:

```
function doThisOnClick(event, ui) {
    console.log("updateVersion, selected = " + $(this).attr('id'));
}

$('[id^=updateVersionItem]').on("click", doThisOnClick);
```

You can either unbind the handler and reattach to all matching items:

```
$('[id^=updateVersionItem]').off("click", doThisOnClick);
$('[id^=updateVersionItem]').on("click", doThisOnClick);
```

Or just dynamically add it to the new items once you add it:

```
$("#updateVersionsList").append('<li><a id="updateVersionItem-' + (i+3) + '">' + versions[i] + '</a></li>').on("click", doThisOnClick);
```

Comment: `.live()` is depreciated as of jQuery 1.7, it's currently still packaged in jQuery but it will be removed. You can however use `.on()` exactly like `.live()` like this: `$(document).on('click', '[id^=updateVersionItem]', function () {...})`. Also, Delegating event handlers binds to the root selected element, in the case of `.live()`, that is the `document` element. So `.live()` doesn't automatically bind to elements as they are added to the DOM, it binds to an element that is always present in the DOM and checks the `event.target` property to detect if a delegated element was acted upon.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks, good information to know!  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: One more thing, `.unbind()` has been replaced by `.off()` to be consistant with the new `.on()` method. `.unbind()` is not slated for removal however it's just a shortcut for `.off()` now.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks again, right now I've been focused on using jQuery 1.4.4, because that's what our app uses, so I haven't been familiarizing myself with what's in 1.7+

Answer (score 0):

create a new function and call it for default and dynamic elements

```
<a onclick="myfunction()">
```

Comment: You mean add that to the HTML you're generating for them? I think the accepted answer is neater.

Comment: by calling a function from the DOM (original or appended) you can skip attaching jquery handlers. edit: i agree with the accepted answer, just posting a different solution