# change class if click again

Tags: jquery, list, onclick

i cobbled me a script to made an accordion.  Now i have the following problem, the active element became the class ".active" with the .click(function(), but if i click again the active element, it does not remove the class. I've tried many solutions and read questions like this: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559585/change-element-class-on-first-click-then-click-again-and-change-back-to-normal) but nothing work...

Here you can find a fiddle of my code:

```
$(function() {
   $("a.dropdown-link").click(function() {
      $("a.dropdown-link").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      return false;
   });
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6tZm/)

If anything is unclear please let me know.

Comment: why remove and adding the same class?

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan he's removing the class from siblings, and adding it to the one which was clicked. It's a standard pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the clicked element already has the `active` class and remove it, otherwise you need to add it. Try this:

```
$("a.dropdown-link").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var func = $(this).hasClass('active') ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass';
    $("a.dropdown-link").removeClass("active");
    $(this)[func]("active");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/n6tZm/2/)

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I have doubt, it is necessary to check whether it has class, does this throw any error if there is no class active `$("a.dropdown-link").removeClass("active");`?

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan no, calling a function on an empty jQuery object (which is what you get if the selector is not found) does not cause an error. Similarly, if the class does not exist, there is no error. jQuery is nice like that :)

Comment: then why we need the conditional check?  The OP's code should have worked right?   Please correct me if I meant wrong.

Comment: No, in his original code in the fiddle, clicking `Stuff 1` opened the options, and changed the arrow. Clicking `Stuff 1` again the arrow does not change because the class is not removed. Try the same in my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this function: 
    $(function() {

```
  $("a.dropdown-link").click(function() {

  var class_anchor = $(this).attr('class');
   if(class_anchor == "dropdown-link active")
   {
       $("a.dropdown-link").removeClass("active");
   }else
   {
         $(this).addClass("active");
   }         
   return false;

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way too

```
  $("a.dropdown-link").click(function() {
      $("a.dropdown-link").not(this).removeClass("active");
   $(this).toggleClass("active");
      return false;

   });
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/n6tZm/3/

Answer (score -1):

Maybe all you need is to use toggleClass instead of remove and add?

```
$(function() {
 $("a.dropdown-link").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Seems to fix it.